# How To Install .APK File With Data (Games) On Windroye?

Tags: installation, apk, root, windroy

I'm Using Windroye 2.9.It's working perfect but there is a question for me.I have installed plants vs zombies 2 recently and have the data of game, but I don't know where I should copy the data to work on windroye.Is there any root folder to copy this data files in??PLS somebody help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You are going to need to download Google Play Games as I believe your game data is stored there. Then, when you run the game, it should link to the app and your data should be restored